# How do I downsample a .wav file in C and apply bandpass filter?

Tags: c, audio, wav

I need to take a .wav file with 44.1k and downsample it to 11.25k (Dividing samples by 4).

I also need to apply a bandpass filter to 300 Hz -> 3,200 Hz to the .wav file.

I am new to audio programming, I have been trying to research how to specifically approach this task but every search has pointed to a library or tool that would simply make the conversion for me. It's a training exercise for a new position I have acquired (to familiarize myself with both C programming and audio programming) so I have to accomplish it manually.

Thanks

Comment: you could probably do all of this with `Gstreamer`...

Comment: Is Gstreamer a library/tool that would execute the conversions for me? I need to program the algorithms to execute the conversion myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Separate the code that deals with the specifics of .wav files from the specifics of working with audio samples.  There are lots of how-tos on the Web for reading and writing .WAV files, especially PCM samples.
2. Once you have your samples in memory, downsampling is trivial.  You literally take every _n_th sample and throw away the rest.  There are other approaches that might better preserve the fidelity.  For example, you might use a low-pass filter first and then resample the filtered waveform.  A low-pass filter can be implemented with weighted averaging of the recent samples.
3. Bandpass filtering can be accomplished a few ways.  The most direct is to transform the samples from the time domain to the frequency domain, manipulate the signal in frequency space, and transform it back.  The transform used for this is called a Fourier transform.  The most common way to do this in software is with an algorithm called a Fast Fourier Transform (FFT).  It's "fast" because it eliminates a lot of redundant calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Reading up on how to implement a digital filter is probably the first step. I would suggest looking up FIR and IIR filters.

Or if you are lazy, there probably exists several third party libraries that you can use.